# PHP substr Query - Cropping URL

Tags: php, substring, substr

I currently have the string:
"/en/sports/football/"

How do I substr this string to achieve:

"/sports/football/"

Many thanks for any pointers.

Comment: Don't you have any ideas already?

Answer (score 1):

Well, lets take a look: http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

The method signature looks something like this:

> string substr ( string $string , int
>   $start [, int $length ] )
>
> If length is omitted, the substring
>   starting from start until the end of
>   the string will be returned.

So I guess we could do something like this to get characters 3 and onward.

> substr("/en/sports/football/", 3);

Comment: Oooh. Quick follow-up. How do I get it to be 'sports/football/'? So minus the first forward slash.

Answer (score 0):

`explode()` on '/', discard the directory you don't want, then `implode()` on '/'